# Does "new CLASS" return CLASS or CLASS*

Tags: c++, class

This may seem really simple, but I don't know how to actually make a program that tells me this.

Comment: ```new``` always gives you a pointer.

Comment: "but I don't know how to actually make a program that tells me this."  try `foo* f = new foo;` and `foo f = new foo;` only one of them is not a compiler error

Comment: time to get used to a good reference right from the start. I suggest this one: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: `#include <iostream> #include <typeinfo> struct CLASS {}; int main() { auto x = new CLASS; std::cout << typeid(x).name() << "\n"; }`

Comment: A [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is more useful to you at this point than a language reference.

Comment: _I don't know how to actually make a program that tells me this._ https://wandbox.org/permlink/l8HtwzyWLP6D7Gx7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments, `new` will always give you a pointer.

But as `new` implies `delete`, I strongly advise you to take a look at a concept call RAII, especially why it's so popular.

Answer (score 1):

> Does "new CLASS" return CLASS or CLASS*

It returns a pointer to the type of the object that you're trying to allocate.

From [new expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new):

> The new expression attempts to allocate storage and then attempts to construct and initialize either a single unnamed object, or an unnamed array of objects in the allocated storage. The new-expression **returns a prvalue pointer to the constructed object or, if an array of objects was constructed, a pointer to the initial element of the array.**